# Something for a child window analogous to `this`

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am a newcomer to programming. I am writing a dialog based application which has a static control on it. Using

```
Using
void CMy1stDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (this == GetCapture())
    {
        CClientDC aDC(this);
        aDC.SetPixel(point, RGB(255,0,0));
    }   
}
```

I can create results like 
[image]

However what I want is that the locus of mouse is only drawn within the static window. I can't find the reference to `this` in MSDN and I don't know why the following method fails.

```
void CMy1stDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CWnd* pMYSTATIC = GetDlgItem (IDC_MYSTATIC);    //IDC_MYSTATIC is the ID of the static control
    if (pMYSTATIC == GetCapture())
    {
        CClientDC aDC(pMYSTATIC);
        aDC.SetPixel(point, RGB(255,0,0));
    }   
}
```

How can I get what I want? Are there any methods to get something for the static window analogous to `this`? I will appreciate any help with these.

Comment: Please read a book about Windows programming. Painting should only be done inside a WM_PAINT message of a window! Than all your problems you are asking here are gone.

Comment: This is wrong, because you paint ("draw" actually) on the dialog window (`CClientDC aDC(this)`) - you should instead paint/draw on the static control, as this is obscures this part of the dialog window. And @xMRI, not really, `CClientDC()` calls `GetDC()`, which doesn't require invalidating and processing the `WM_PAINT` message, it's used exactly for direct "Drawing".

Comment: Oops, sorry, just realized I was wrong, you already draw on the dialog because your static control is just a frame. Try `GetDlgItem(IDC_MYSTATIC))->GetWindowRect()` (or `pMYSTATIC->GetWindowRect()`)  and then `PtInRect(&rect, &point)` to check if you are inside the desired rectangle. The rectangle may need to be shrunk (to its client-only area).

Comment: You cannot hope to become proficient at MFC without a *solid* understanding of the Windows API. Start with Petzold's [Programming Windows®](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try this:

```
void CMy1stDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CRect rect;
    // Get static control's rectangle
    GetDlgItem(IDC_MYSTATIC)->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    // Convert it to client coordinates
    ScreenToClient(&rect);
    // Check if mouse pointer is inside the static window, if so draw the pixel
    if (rect.PtInRect(point))
    {
        CClientDC dc(this);
        dc.SetPixel(point.x, point.y, RGB(255,0,0));
    }
}
```

This code may need some fixes too, eg shrink the rectangle (to its client-only area), before checking whether to draw the pixel.

Please note that you don't need to check `GetCapture()`; if your dialog hasn't captured the mouse it won't be receiving this message anyway.

Also, all these functions are wrappers of Windows SDK ones, eg the `ClientDC()` class, basically wraps `GetDC()`/`ReleaseDC()`.

Comment: Dear @Constantine Georgiou: Thank you so much for your kind and useful reply. Sorry I have no right to upvote your answer now. Your answer helps me clarify the difference between `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect`.

Comment: Since I need coordinates to be relative to the upper-left corner of the static (that is, the upper-left of the static is (0,0)), I adjust your `ScreenToClient(&rect);` and `CClientDC dc(this);` respectively as follows: `GetDlgItem(IDC_MYSTATIC)->ScreenToClient(&rect);` and `CClientDC dc (GetDlgItem (IDC_BGSTATIC));`. However, after my adjustment, I find the locus falls behind the mouse. How can I overcome this? Thank you.

Comment: Umm, the `point` struct (ok, class) is relative to the dialog client area here (so is that `CClientDC dc(this)`). But the `CClientDC dc (GetDlgItem (IDC_BGSTATIC))` is in the static's client area coordinates. So you need to convert it. Since there is no way of direct client-to-client conversion, I would call `ClientToScreen(&point)` and then `GetDlgItem (IDC_BGSTATIC)->ScreenToClient(&point)`. If you don't (usually you don't) the static window in the dialog, the conversion is just an offset, and you could store the result of the first conversion and use this instead of calling the functions.