# Invalidate() and child_wnd_name.InvalidateRect (&rect) cause different results

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am writing a dialog based application which has one static control, one button and two edit controls. The static's type is `class MyStatic : public CStatic` which has an `OnPaint()` defined as follows:

```
void MyStatic::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    int Row = pBGDlg->iRow;          //pBGDlg is a pointer to the dialog
    int Column = pBGDlg->iColumn;    //iRow and iColumn are variables of the two edit controls
    int RowHei = pBGDlg->iRowHei;
    int ColumnWid = pBGDlg->iColumnWid;

    if (bBuPressed)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Row; ++i)
        {
            dc.MoveTo (0, i * RowHei);
            dc.LineTo (Column * ColumnWid, i * RowHei);
        }
    }
```

Whenever the user input two integers and press the button, the application will draw corresponding lines on the static

```
void CProjDlg::OnClickedIdpreview()
{
    UpdateData ();
    mystatic.GetClientRect (&rtStatic);        //mystatic is the name of the static
    iRowHei = (rtStatic.Height () - 1) / iRow;  
    iColumnWid = (rtStatic.Width () - 1) / iColumn;

    mystatic.bBuPressed = true;
    Invalidate ();  
    UpdateWindow ();
}
```

For Example:[Input 4 to the 1st edit control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iPK0.jpg) and then [input 1 to the 1st edit control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCaZ9.jpg). However, if I substitute `mystatic.InvalidateRect(&rtStatic);` and `mystatic.UpdateWindow();` for `Invalidate();` and `UpdateWindow();` respectively, the application fails to erase previous results. For example: [Input 4 to the 1st edit control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iPK0.jpg) and then [input 5 to the 1st edit control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hJQL.jpg). I can not figure out why the second method fails. Could anyone explain for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You won't succeed by guessing, what the code you write does. My [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178788/something-for-a-child-window-analogous-to-this#comment81411753_47178788) is still true. You need to take a step back, learn the Windows API *thoroughly*, before you even have a chance to understand an abstraction layered on top of it.

Comment: Hint: Your dialog is created using the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` [window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx).

Comment: Try `mystatic.Invalidate()`, comment out `Invalidate()` and `UpdateWindow` if you don't need them.

Comment: You need to show more of your code.

Comment: Of course they cause different results, because they are different operations. In the former case you will receive a WM_PAINT message for the main window, in the latter a  WM_DRAWITEM one (if your control is owner-drawn); or you can subclass the static control by supplying its own window procedure.